# Internet Explorer 11 x Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

Estou com um problema na utilização dos relatórios no `Internet Explorer 11`. Em modo de compatibilidade todos funcionam, mas da forma normal, o `Report Viewer` abre exibe os controles, mas não renderiza os dados.

Já adicionei a pasta `App_Browsers` com o arquivo `.browser` conforme recomendado em alguns fóruns, e já inclui na `Master Page` do projeto a linha `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />`.

A versão do Report é a 10. Meu `web.config` está com as linhas abaixo:

```
<handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
           type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
  <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Estava com o mesmo problema no **Internet Explorer 11**, pois no **Internet Explorer 9** funciona normalmente.

Estou usando o Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms 10.

Tentei vários tipos de tag META citados aqui
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966521(v=vs.85).aspx e aqui
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528(v=vs.85).aspx,
mas nenhuma delas funcionou.

Como ReportViewer WebForms é usado em um sistema corporativo com poucos usuários, a solução temporária que encontrei foi adicionar a URL do sistema no
Modo de Exibição de Compatibilidade diretamente no IE na janela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funcionou pelo menos até encontrar uma solução melhor.

---

### Atualização

Solução definitiva.

Atualize para o Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms 11.
Download: http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=35747

É necessário atualizar o projeto no Visual Studio adicionando referência  "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll" geralmente localizado em "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReportViewer".

Voltou a funcionar normalmente.